# How to wrap a text on a UIButton in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, uilabel

I try to wrap a text on a button as follow:

```
nextButton=UIButton(frame: CGRectMake(buttonHWidth, textHeigth, buttonHWidth, buttonHeigth));

        nextButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor()
        nextButton.setTitle("", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        nextButton.addTarget(self, action: "buttonAction:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
        nextButton.tag = 22;


        label_nextButton = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(buttonHWidth, textHeigth, buttonHWidth, buttonHeigth));
        label_nextButton.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center;
        label_nextButton.numberOfLines = 2;
        label_nextButton.font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(16.0);
        label_nextButton.text = "Prss next Press next";
        label_nextButton.textColor=UIColor.blackColor();

        nextButton.addSubview(label_nextButton);
        self.view.addSubview(nextButton);
```

I can see the button on the device, but I don't see any text.

What am I doing wrong ? Or can this be done without adding a label to a button ?
Thanks for helping.

Illustration. It looks like :

[image]

When just doing:

```
nextButton.setTitle("this is a very very long text", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You need to write text in the setTitle method:

```
nextButton.setTitle("This is the very very long text!", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
```

Set the number of lines and wrap mode to the title label:

```
nextButton.titleLabel.numberOfLines = 0; // Dynamic number of lines
nextButton.titleLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
```

> Update to Swift 4

```
nextButton.titleLabel.numberOfLines = 0; // Dynamic number of lines
nextButton.titleLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.byWordWrapping;
```

Comment: Thanks, but : This doesn't wrap the text. A text like "This is a very very long text" will be shortened in my case to "This is a v...y long text".

Comment: @user1344545 are you using AutoLayout in StoryBoard?

Comment: No. I like to do all at runtime with the above code.

Comment: Hi, I don't understand. I added a picture to illustrate what I mean. I have a fixed size button and I would like to have the text on the button on several lines wrapped. So far I did not succeed with setTitle.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks a lot for the effort !

Comment: For Swift versions 2.1+ use programCell.room.titleLabel?.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.ByWordWrapping

Answer (score 4):

**Swift 4**

To shorten text by replacing the middle of the text with "..." you should use NSLineBreakMode.byWordWrapping:

```
nextButton.titleLabel?.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.byWordWrapping
```

To shorten the text by replacing the end of the text with "..." you should use NSLineBreakMode.byTruncatingTail:

```
nextButton.titleLabel?.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.byTruncatingTail
```

To see the full list of available wrapping modes check out the NSLineBreakMode documentation: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nslinebreakmode